# Slow performance of Python multiprocessing when run under SLURM

Tags: python, multiprocessing, slurm

I am running a Python code that employs `multiprocessing` for parallel tasks. When I run this on my local machine, everything works as expected, but when I use a cluster of 2x AMD with 64 cores per node, everything slows down significantly. I am using SLURM for the batch execution, **and I want to run the parallel version on a single node**, just employing the total 64x2 cores for that single node.

When no parallelization occurs (serial execution), calling the script is done via:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2G
#SBATCH --cpus_per_task=64
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --nstaks-per-node=1

module load python
python 0 myscript.py
```

The 0 input indicates that the script should run serialized, i.e. there is no call to the multiprocessing module internally. Let's say this takes about ~ 5 minutes.

Now, when I call for a parallel calculation, the sh file is changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2G
#SBATCH --cpus_per_task=64
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --nstaks-per-node=1

module load python

export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

python 1 64 myscript.py
```

The 1 input now indicates that the script should call the multiprocessing module for parallel calculation, whereas 64 indicates that a total of 64 processes should be created by the `multiprocessing.Pool()`. Here, each of the processes created from the multiprocessing module take about~30mins to complete, whereas in my local machine, each process takes around 5 mins, same as with the serialized call.

I have also seen that when using `sacct` to monitor the job, SLURM says the number of CPUS allocated equals 128, and not 64 as specified in the `cpus_per_task`.

So I am failing to understand this time differences, and I feel this could be on how SLURM is called from the batch, but the resources specifications seem correct to me. It is also strange that in my machine, which has 4x2 cores, the parallel processing works as expected, with each process taking ~ 5 mins.

**EDIT**: I have made some tests. I observe that when I keep the MKL_NUM_THREADS=2 and run for 16 processes to complete 32 workers in the parallelization, it takes shorter time than when I run with 32 processes to complete 32 workers in the parallelization. Could this be due to some inter-processing communication taking place? In my parallel function, there is no modified shared data between processes, and being a fork parallelization, I would expect each child process to be independent from the parent one.

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue? I have the same identical problem

Comment: Same, any solution that you found?